# Vuetify open datepicker nr 2 on datepicker nr 1's value

Tags: datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm having two datepickers from vuetify. I want them to be synked so if i choose for example 1 december 2020 in the first picker, I want the second picker to open on december, and not today.
Someone who has done the same thing?

I've searched through vuetifys documentation for datepickers and tried props like 'picker-date' but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same v-model to both it they do the same job.